# file_exists return false after /usr/bin/convert

Tags: php, shell-exec, file-exists

Some thumbs are created on server using shell_exec("/usr/bin/convert -thumbnail..), the files are created properly on server, but file_exists returns false for few seconds after the thumbs  are created.

If I add sleep(5) before file_exists then file_exists return true.

Why file_exists returns false?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Why file_exists returns false?!

Comment: What is your file system? Are you positive you use `shell_exec`?

Comment: File system on the server is ext3.
Yes, shell_exec is used.

Answer (score 0):

If sleep(5) added between means creating a file is taking time, means for file_exists() there is a file which is creating and its creation is in progress (as file_exists checks for its physical presence). Try to get success from shell_exec() and only if this returns true go for nest operation.

```
if ( shell_exec("/usr/bin/convert -thumbnail..) )
    file_exists(FILE);
```